# JUnit5 Platform Launcher API - Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine

Tags: java, junit5, serviceloader

I am attempting to upgrade the testing abilities of our automated testing suite to accept JUnit5 tests and when following The [JUnit Platform Launcher API instructions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api) I get the error **"Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath"**. The cause is that the following is unable to find any instances of `TestEngine`:

`Iterable<TestEngine> testEngines = ServiceLoader.load(TestEngine.class,ClassLoaderUtils.getDefaultClassLoader());`

Do you have any suggestions on how to ensure that the `ServiceLoader` is able to find an instance of `TestEngine`?

I have included `org.junit.jupiter.engine`, which contains `JupiterTestEngine` which implements `TestEngine`, as a required plugin. I have tried adding a direct path to the jupiter.engine jar in the project's .classpath. I have tried creating an instance of `JupiterTestEngine` witihn the same file and it is created successfully, but still no `TestEngine`s found by the service loader.

EDIT (In response to Sormuras's comment):

This is for Eclipse and you can see the code base here:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.test

I added the following to the mainifest:

```
org.junit.platform.launcher,
org.junit.jupiter.api;bundle-version="5.0.0",
org.junit.platform.engine;bundle-version="1.0.0",
org.junit.platform.commons;bundle-version="1.0.0",
org.junit.jupiter.engine;bundle-version="5.0.0",
org.junit.vintage.engine;bundle-version="4.12.0"
```

Added this to the .classplath:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/home/lbullen/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.junit.jupiter.engine_5.0.0.v20170910-2246.jar"/>
```

Added the org.junit.jupiter.engine jar to the lib folder then added it to be included in the binary build. (I'm streatching for a solution)

And I'm trying to get the Tutorial code to work in an edited version of http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.test/src/org/eclipse/test/EclipseTestRunner.java with all the old junit code removed.

Comment: What does class or module path look like?

Comment: @Sormuras Check edits.

Comment: Does following the example explained here https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php help?