# Java Exception No Tests Found Matching when Junit5 ParameterizedTest Attempt

Tags: java, junit5, parameterized-tests

SO I am trying to use ParameterizedTest from JUnit5 and setup the pom to load everything and now have the following test class.

```
    import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.tdameritrade.ctg.cashmovement.enums.transaction.TransactionProcessEnum;
import com.tdameritrade.ctg.cashmovement.enums.transaction.TransactionStatusEnum;
import com.tdameritrade.ctg.junit.categories.UnitTest;

/**
 * Test class for Posting Common Utils
 */
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@Category(UnitTest.class)
public class PostingCommonUtilsTest {

    private static Stream<Arguments> dataSetForTransactionStatus() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of(TransactionStatusEnum.ERRORED.getName(), true),
                         Arguments.of(TransactionStatusEnum.COMPLETED.getName(), false));
    }

    /**
     * Test method for
     * {@link com.tdameritrade.ctg.cashmovement.posting.PostingCommonUtils#checkTransactionErrored(java.lang.String)}.
     */
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("dataSetForTransactionStatus")
    public void testCheckTransactionErrored(final String status, final boolean result) throws Exception {
        assertThat(PostingCommonUtils.checkTransactionErrored(status), is(equalTo(result)));
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testCheckTransactionErrored], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testCheckTransactionErrored(com.tdameritrade.ctg.cashmovement.posting.PostingCommonUtilsTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.tdameritrade.ctg.cashmovement.posting.PostingCommonUtilsTest,fLeadingIdentifier=testCheckTransactionErrored]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@654f0d9c
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Maybe I missed it but I have tried searching this error and everything I have found points back to things that are already set.  For example, one article said that the pom was not together right, but I have the same thing they do.

Here is my pom.xmls:

PARENT POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
...  
      <properties>
...
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.3.2</junit.platform.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>

...
</project>
```

CHILD POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tdameritrade.ctg</groupId>
        <artifactId>cashmovement-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../cashmovement-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <name>CTG Cash Movement Server</name>
    <groupId>com.tdameritrade.ctg</groupId>
    <artifactId>cashmovement-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
            <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
            <version>${junit-addons.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>${surefire.fork.count}</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>${surefire.fork.reuse}</reuseForks>
                    <groups>${maven.surefire.include.groups}</groups>
                    <excludedGroups>${maven.surefire.exclude.groups}</excludedGroups>
                    <properties>
                        <includeTags>junit5</includeTags>
                    </properties>                    
                </configuration>
...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What is wrong?

If I run via command line, this is the stack trace of the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project cashmovement-common: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project cashmovement-common: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:579)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your stack trace it looks like you are attempting to start a JUnit 5 test with `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader`. That's unlikely to work, same problem [as reported in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143043/running-eclipse-junit-plug-in-tests-using-junit5).

Try running the test using Maven from the command line as explained in [Running a Single Test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) docs:

```
mvn -Dtest=PostingCommonUtilsTest test
```

If the test runs successfully or you see exactly the same exception as in Eclipse than your Eclipse setup is correct and it's an issue with frameworks. Otherwise your Eclipse setup is flawed and doesn't support JUnit 5.

It could be an issue with Eclipse version. According to official [Embracing JUnit 5 with Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php) page:

> We do not support running tests in a setup where an old Eclipse build (not having JUnit 5 support) is using a new Eclipse build (having JUnit 5 support) as target. Also, developers who have the JDT JUnit runtime bundles (org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime, org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime) checked out and pull the latest changes will run into the above issue. You are expected to use a new Eclipse build for the development.

Comment: So I am using Eclipse 4.5.2.

Comment: No. It is "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test"

Comment: @PatrickAquilone As per [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_UI/JUnit_5#Eclipse_support_for_JUnit_5_is_available_from_Eclipse_Oxygen.1a_.284.7.1a.29.) you need Eclipse 4.7.1 or 4.8 or newer for JUnit 5 support. Kindly provide a full stack trace with the root cause. It's impossible to guess.

Comment: Added stack trace in original question since it won't fit here.

Comment: Although it may just be that my Eclipse isn't late enough

Comment: Are you sure `PostingCommonUtilsTest` is in the default package as in your code example? You can't omit the package name for `-Dtest` it requires a fully qualified name. Also your Maven Surefire Plugin is outdated as hell.

Comment: I get the same error if I use the full test name with package.
"mvn -Dtest=com.tdameritrade.ctg.cashmovement.posting.PostingCommonUtilsTest test -e"

Answer (score 2):

For JUnit5, you need to use the `@ExtendWith` instead of the `@RunWith` under your test class.